# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in myfile on line 1

Tags: php, syntax

Here's my code:

```
<?php

if(empty($_POST['id']))
{
    echo '<form method="post"><input type="text" name="id"><input type="submit" value="go"></form>';
}
else
{   

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","adminuser","adminpassword","database");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        die("dbconnect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $remoteEndpoint=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"].".".$_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"];
    $hash = md5(uniqid());
    $code= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `mobile` (`useragent`, `ip`, `hash`) VALUES ('".$code."', '".$remoteEndpoint."','".$hash."')");

    echo hash;
}

?>
```

With this, I'm getting

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /mylocation/index.php on line 1
```

I've checked all the branches and I can't find anything.

Did I miss something?

Comment: [Your file works.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GH5xUx)

Comment: Not the problem, but you forgot a `$` on the `echo hash` line. should be `echo $hash`

Comment: @j08691 no, this is the only file

Comment: @ArsenZahray You should learn how to debug your own scripts. Start by removing one part at a time. Narrow down the source of the problem. There are a billion posts about basic PHP syntax/parsing errors on SO and none of them are useful to anyone (notice the sidebar on the right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code does not report the error you suggest "error: syntax error, unexpected $end"

I've tested it on my local dev and while I obviously get access denied warning for the mysql connection, there are no PHP errors.

There is a notice:
"PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant hash - assumed 'hash' "

Because as pointed out by Marc B you missed the $ on the end of your "hash" var.

This means there must be more to your code, and the actual issue is in there somewhere. Commonly (note, not always, but often) the unexpected $end error is due to a missing curly bracket (ie you opened an IF but didn't close it). Check those first. If you don't use an editor with syntax highlighting, you should as it often saves time on those daft typos and late-night-tired mistakes...